# DateFormat month to uppercase

Tags: java, simpledateformat, date-format, date-formatting, uppercase

How to format the date to the following view OCTOBER 21, 2018 (the month in upper case)? I can get it by `"%1$TB %1$te, %1$tY"` pattern, but I need to do it by SimpleDateFormat. Can you suggest me how I can do it?

Comment: I recommend you avoid the `SimpleDateFormat` class. It is not only long outdated, it is also notoriously troublesome. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 6):

You can do something like this:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM dd, yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
String dateStr = sdf.format(new Date());
System.out.println( dateStr.toUpperCase() );
```

Brief Description:

first we create an instance of *SimpleDateFormat* and pass as parameter the default "MMMM dd, yyyy" which will result in "Month day, year".

Then we pass the current date (`new Date ()` or your date) to the class *SimpleDateFormat* to do the conversion.

Finally, we use `toUpperCase()` so that the text is uppercase.

I hope I've helped! :D

Comment: I have a weird insecurity with toUpperCase() and toLowerCase(). If for some reason your code ever runs in April on a computer set on Turkish as default language, you'll get: APRİL 21, 2018. Notice the dot on the capital I. I always call them like dateStr.toUpperCase(Locale.ROOT)

Answer (score 4):

`SimpleDateFormat` cannot give you that (though you just might consider if you can develop a subclass that can). But `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API, can:

```
    Map<Long, String> monthNames = Arrays.stream(Month.values())
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(m -> Long.valueOf(m.getValue()), Month::toString));
    DateTimeFormatter dateFormatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
            .appendText(ChronoField.MONTH_OF_YEAR, monthNames)
            .appendPattern(" d, uuuu")
            .toFormatter();
    LocalDate date = LocalDate.of(2018, Month.OCTOBER, 21);
    String formattedDate = date.format(dateFormatter);
    System.out.println(formattedDate);
```

Output from this snippet is what you requested:

> OCTOBER 21, 2018

I have assumed you need this in English only. For other languages you would just have to populate the map differently.

This is just as well because you shouldn’t want to use `SimpleDateFormat` anyway. That class is not only long outdated, it is also renowned for being troublesome. `java.time` is generally so much nicer to work with.

**Link:** [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use `java.time`.